# How can I detect specific item of listview reach the top of the screen?

Tags: android

What I want is when I scroll (for example the Title2) to the top, the **big Title** will be changed according to the title at the top at that moment (Title2).

The **big Title** is just a LinearLayout above the ListView and the smal titles in Listview are items of the List. So I have an idea is to detect if a specific item reached to the top of or not, but I don't know how. Please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set [AbsListView.OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) to ListView first. Then use [AdapterView.getFirstVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition()) to get the first displayed item.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private ListView mList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mList.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(50));
        mList.setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
            int totalItemCount) {
        // This is the position within the adapter's data set
        // for the first item displayed on screen.
        int firstPosition = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        // Determine whether change title or not

    }
}
```